# Pymodbus: GUI (Graphical User Interface) stops/crashes when a SerialServer starts

Tags: python, user-interface, pyserial, pymodbus

**Versions:**
Python: 3.9 |
Pymodbus: 2.5.1

**Pymodbus Specific:**
Server: rtu - sync/async |
Client: rtu - sync/async

**Description:**

I want to start the SerialServer of pymodbus after clicking a button on the graphical user interface.
But after a click on the button the Gui stops and I have to stop my programm.
It is not possible to run the SerialServer while the Gui is open.

```
from pymodbus.version import version
from pymodbus.server.asynchronous import StartSerialServer
#from pymodbus.server.sync import StartSerialServer
from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSparseDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer

import sys
from qtpy import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

def modbus_send():
    class CustomDataBlock(ModbusSparseDataBlock):
        def setValues(self, address, value):
            super(CustomDataBlock, self).setValues(0, 10)
            super(CustomDataBlock, self).setValues(1, 11)
            super(CustomDataBlock, self).setValues(2, 12)
            #print("wrote {} to {}".format(value, address))

    block = CustomDataBlock({0: [0] * 100})
    store = ModbusSlaveContext(hr=block)
    context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store)

    identity = ModbusDeviceIdentification()
    identity.VendorName = 'pymodbus'
    identity.ProductCode = 'PM'
    identity.VendorUrl = 'http://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/'
    identity.ProductName = 'pymodbus Server'
    identity.ModelName = 'pymodbus Server'
    identity.MajorMinorRevision = version.short()

    StartSerialServer(context, framer=ModbusRtuFramer, identity=identity, port='COM7', timeout=0.05, baudrate=19200)

window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
window.setWindowTitle("StartSerialServer")
window.setGeometry(500, 500, 500, 50)

button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(window)
button.setText("Start")
button.show()
button.clicked.connect(modbus_send())

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: you may have to run it in separated thread because it blocks `GUI`. GUI waits for end of this server and it can't run own code which get key/mouse event from system, send then to widgets, update/redraw widgets - so it looks like it is stoped.

Comment: `connect` needs  function's name without `()` - so called `"callback"` - `connect(modbus_send)`. And when you click button then it will use `()` to run this function.

Comment: With the seperated thread my application worked!